# Opencart config.php needs to be writable

Tags: iis, opencart, windows-server

I am attempting to install opencart on my windows server with IIS. I have set the permissions of the directly to include modify. But I'm still getting this message:

[image]

I have copied the files per the instructions to this location: `C:\opencart`

Here are the permission I've set:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you have to make sure the following ***folders*** and ***files*** permissions allow Read and Write. Not just setting the Opencart folder permissions.

- **config.php**
- **admin/config.php**

Reference steps: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/INSTALL.md#windows-install

OpenCart Community reference case: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=10085